# Dynamically Loading External Modules in a C Program?

Tags: c++, c, dynamic, modularity

I'm sure this problem has been solved before and I'm curious how its done. I have code in which, when run, I want to scan the contents of a directory and load in functionality.

Specifically, I am working with a scripting engine that I want to be able to add function calls to. I want the core engine to provide very limited functionality. The user should be able to add additional functions through 3rd party libraries, which I want the engine to scan for and load. How is this done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the platform. On win32, you call `LoadLibrary` to load a DLL, then get functions from it with `GetProcAddress`. On Unixy platforms, the equivalents are `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the POSIX dlopen/dlsym/dlerror/dlclose functions in Linux/UNIX to dynamically open shared libraries and access the symbols (including functions) they provide, see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) for details.

Comment: You can find many examples in existing programs. Shameless plug: my program echoping http://echoping.sourceforge.net/ is a relatively simple exemple of such an use of dlopen().

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a library for this, I'd recommend GLib (the utility library that lies underneath the GTK+ UI toolkit). It features the "[GModule](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html)" sub-API, which provides a clean, portable way of doing this. This saves you from having to wrap the relevant calls yourself, and also brings you the rest of GLib which is *very* handy to have in C programs of any size.